# How to provide arguments to Readline functions via inputrc

Tags: bash, readline

I'm trying to use the `insert-comment` function provided by readline to uncomment a line.
According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-insert_002dcomment-_0028M_002d_0023_0029):

> If a numeric argument is supplied, this command acts as a toggle: if the characters at the beginning of the line do not match the value of comment-begin, the value is inserted, otherwise the characters in comment-begin are deleted from the beginning of the line

I have following line in my `.inputrc` for it:

```
"\eW": insert-comment 1
```

Which maps `insert-comment` to <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> (just for testing. I intend to remap <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>#</kbd> when it works)

On reloading `.inputrc`, entering some text on the terminal (like `#123`) and then pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, `#` gets prepended to whatever I type (like `##123`), the same behaviour as <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>#</kbd>.

How do I use `insert-comment` function as a toggle mapped to a custom key sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Readline doesn't support adding an argument in a binding like this. You can define a macro, though. For example, suppose you left `insert-comment` bound to Alt-W. Then you could define Alt-# as

```
"\e#": "\e1\eW"
```

The `\e1` sets the argument to 1, followed by `\eW` to invoke `insert-comment` with the current argument.